# When using NSCalender and NSDateComponents how to set the first day of the week?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

Users of my app will have the option to select their preferred first day of a week (i.e. week starts on Thursday).

How can I adjust the first day of week using NSCalender and NSDateComponents?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSCalendar first day of week](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106943/nscalendar-first-day-of-week)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
[calendar setFirstWeekday:5]; // 5 = Thursday, 1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, etc.
```