# How to get first day of the week in IOS 

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSCalendar first day of week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106943/nscalendar-first-day-of-week)

I need first date of the week for that I'm having weekNumberOfThe Year and Year.

I got this solution:

```
[components setYearForWeekOfYear:year];
[components setWeekOfYear:week];
[components setWeekday:2];
```

This is working on IOS 5 +, but not working on IOS less than 5, i.e. 4 and 4.3 likewise