# Get day of week in number starting with Monday, NOT Sunday?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I used

```
[currentComps setFirstWeekday:2];
```

It returns the number of the day of week starting with Sunday. How should I hardcode returning this number starting with Monday?

Comment: Your question is unclear. `setFirstWeekday:` is a method of `NSCalendar`, not `NSDateComponents`, so your code cannot compile. - In the Gregorian calendar, 1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, ... is fixed, you cannot change that. With `[calendar setFirstWeekday:2]` you can specify that Monday is considered as "start of the week" in all calculations. That does not change the fact that 2 = Monday.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSCalendar first day of week](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106943/nscalendar-first-day-of-week)

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the comment by Martin R, you can use `NSCalendar` to specify the first day of the week via:

```
- (void)setFirstWeekday:(NSUInteger)weekday
```

Reading the documentation of `NSCalendar`, it states the method `setFirstWeekday:`

`Sets the index of the first weekday for the receiver.`

I haven't tried this myself, but I would assume that creating an instance of `NSCalendar`, calling the aforementioned method and also calling `setCalendar:` on your `NSDateComponents` would attenuate all dates components returned to work as you intend.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean by *"...  all dates components returned to work as you intend"*, but Sunday is **always** represented as `1` in the `weekDay` property of `NSDateComponents` (assuming the Gregorian calendar). - The purpose of `setFirstWeekday:` is to determine the "start of the week" in calendrical calculations, for example `[calendar rangeOfUnit:NSWeekCalendarUnit ...]` to compute the beginning of a week. Some regions consider Monday as the first day in the week, other regions have Sunday as the first day in the week. But in any case: Sunday = 1, Monday = 2.